# OpenCL: copy from constant memory directly to global output corrupts data

Tags: opencl

Is this a driver bug, or are you required to copy to local memory before going back out to global? The broken version has the same byte position corrupted in each output.

```
    __kernel void test(__constant item_t items[], __constant uint *xs, uint stride, __global ushort8 *output)
    {
        ushort8 stats;
        size_t id = get_global_id(0);

        xs += id * stride;

        //stats = items[xs[0]].stats; output[id] = stats;  -- this works
        output[id] = items[xs[0]].stats;                   // this doesn't.
    }
```

Tested on Geforce GTX 280, driver 331.82, Windows 8.1 64bit.

Edit: 
Nevermind copying locally to 'stats' doesn't fix it.

Edit2:

- __constant ushort8 input gives corrupted results.
- __global ushort8  input gives OK results.
- __constant ushort[8] --> OK.
- __global ushort[8] --> OK.

Comment: This reminds me of an old problem I had. Referring an array with [] instead with a proper fixed value made the compiler mesh up the code... There has to be a simple explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/470881/use-of-constant-memory-breaks-with-opencl-1-1-constant-memory-worked-fine-in-1-0-but-fails-in-1-1/

> Ok, so, the problem is that declaring all the global scope variables as __constant I exceeded the maximum number of possible __constant variables and when this happens the content of the __constant variables will be random...
>
> In simpler words, you have to count all the times that you use the
>   __constant keyword in the *.cl source file and this number has to be less than the maximum number of possible __constant variables
>   supported by the device in use.

Comment: Is this limit enforced by translation unit or for a whole program?

Comment: As far as I tested, 2 constants should not be any problem, and why does it work just by not assigning to private? Even with the 2 constants there?. It has to be another problem. I would bet for some casting problem with the "items" array.

Comment: The full file had at least 15 __constant variable aliases, most of which pointed to the same buffer. No kernel had more than 4 __constant inputs. Making some __constant buffers __global seems to have fixed it. I assumed CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS was only related to the inputs of any given kernel and not all constant references in the file. Either way, the behavior is pretty odd.